# Listview setOnScrollListener scroll up down

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I have a `ListView`, I want to show/hide some content regarding the scroll event.

When it's scrolling down, I want to hide one layout (passing to `gone`) which is above the ListView. On scroll up, I want to show this layout. I wrote a working code, but I have a problem.

When I slowly scroll my ListView, I have a very bad result: my ListView jumps (but only when I do it slowly).

This is my source:

```
main_listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
                Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling up");
                _title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {
                Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling down");

                MainActivity.azercell_title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            mLastVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
        }

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView,
                int scrollState) {


        }
    });
```

How I can change my code to retrieve the same result (showing/hiding a content on scroll) but without getting some weird jumps?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
                    {
                        if(flag_loading == false)
                        {
                            flag_loading = true;

                        }
                    }        
                }
            });
```

note : after setting the adapter for new pagination items set

`flag_loading = true;`

Comment: no you meybe did not understand me.i want show my layout listview scroll up and hide listview scroll down